# Incorrect size of the text in the programmatically creating RadioButtons

Tags: android

I'm using different sizes of text for different screen resolutions. To do this, I created a resource values/dimens.xml and values-sw720dp/dimens.xml. It was seen a feature, on the phone with a resolution of 540x960 size of text RadioButton taken from the values / dimens.xml and on the phone with a resolution of 720x1280 from the values-sw720dp / dimens.xml. But for the rest of items that are not programmatically, as defined in the layout Xml text size is taken correctly. Why is this happening?

```
 RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);

newRadioButton.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.edit_text_size)); 
newRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#002060"));

radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change folder name to values-xhdpi and then check it

Comment: If I change the values-sw720dp to values-xhdpi, the text size will increase, and for the smaller screen. I change folder name to values-xlarge, but nothing has changed with the original problem.

Comment: have you found any problem with specific device ?

Comment: This is the only problem. As I wrote, for the rest of items that are text size defined not programmatically and defined in the layout Xml, text size is taken correctly